# Sort and keep a unique duplicate which has the highest value

Tags: sorting, unix, uniq

I have a file like the one shown below, I want to keep the combinations between the first and second field which has the highest value on the third field(the ones with the arrows, arrows are not included in the actual file) .

```
1   1   10
1   1   12        <- 
1   2   6         <-
1   3   4         <- 
2   4   32
2   4   37
2   4   39
2   4   40        <- 
2   45  12
2   45  15        <- 
3   3   12
3   3   15
3   3   17
3   3   19        <- 
3   15  4
3   15  9         <- 
4   17  25
4   17  28
4   17  32
4   17  36        <- 
4   18  4         <-
```

in order to have and output like this:

```
1   1   12
1   2   6
1   3   4
2   4   40
2   45  15
3   3   19
3   15  9
4   17  36
4   18  4
```

And I thought maybe I just play with the `sort` and `uniq` command, but I made a mess.

Any ideas?

Very important note: the entries are not neatly sorted from the beginning, I just used `sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3`

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: `sort -r -k1 -k2 -k3 x.txt | awk '{if($i!=l1 && $2!=l2)print $0; l1=$1; l2=$2;}'`

Comment: Pretty clever Jerry, and I added some stuff because of the sort, I had to specify thet the sort is by number values and it ended like this:  sort -r -nk1,1 -nk2,2 -nk3,3 | awk '{if($i!=l1 && $2!=l2)print $0; l1=$1; l2=$2;}'     please post your solution in order to give you a green check.

Comment: Give the check to one of the other answers.  The reason I didn't post it as an answer is because it relied on code and it was clear from your comment about sort and uniq that a real answer would be done with just standard commands.  The reason I posted it as a comment was just in case no one else supplied an answer so that you would have something that worked.

Comment: could you explain how awk '{if($i!=l1 && $2!=l2)print $0; l1=$1; l2=$2;}' works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit funny, but:

```
sort -nr myfile.txt | rev | uniq -f1 | rev | sort -n
```

Output:

```
1   1   12
1   2   6 
1   3   4 
2   4   40
2   45  15
3   15  9 
3   3   19
4   17  36
4   18  4
```

How it works:

- Sort reverse numerically, putting the highest values at the top (so they are saved)
- Reverse each line, so the last field is first (needed for `uniq`)
- Save only the first uniq line, but ignoring the first field (was the last field)
- Reverse the line back to original order
- Sort the lines from low to high again

Probably not the most efficient in the world, but at least each step makes some sense.

Comment: I like this answer best!  IT does exactly what he wanted: uses sort and uniq

Comment: Thanks JJ. I liked your approach in the comment, but couldn't actually get it to work.

Comment: just curious: why did you have problems with my idea?  (it worked for me when I tried it)

Comment: Unfortunately, `uniq -f` is a nonportable extension.

Answer (score 2):

Two passes of `sort` should do it, for example in `bash` shell

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3nr -t$'\t'  file  | sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -t$'\t' -u -s
1       1       12
1       2       6
1       3       4
2       4       40
2       45      15
3       3       19
3       15      9
4       17      36
4       18      4
```

Comment: @beroe, perhaps you have space delimiters and not tab? The command above needs tab-delimited input. As you can see from the output I have pasted in, it matches what the OP is looking for. I am using GNU sort on linux

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -nr myfile.txt | rev | uniq -f1 -f2 -f3 -f4 | rev | sort -n
```

The above worked very well for a file I needed to sort 4 columns displaying the highest values for field 2 and 4

```
STORE402        27         8          1          21-04-2021_07:55:01
STORE402        34         8          3          19-04-2021_11:40:01
STORE402        34         8          3          19-04-2021_15:05:01
STORE402        36         8          4          21-04-2021_12:05:01
STORE402        40         8          5          19-04-2021_12:20:01
STORE402        43         8          6          20-04-2021_10:40:01
```

output after running the command:

```
STORE402        43         8          6          20-04-2021_10:40:01
```