# How to Filter a file using awk and sort commands based on second field,Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file like below which I have sorted based on the username field.

```
1234    200   suresh
5678    150   murali
8543    200   sanjith
5678    100   suresh
1456    400  murali
```

I am trying to remove the rows which have the lowest score for the same usernames. So I want to have the output using Shell Script.

```
1234    200   suresh
5678    400   murali
8543    200   sanjith
```

Comment: Hi there, please format your examples and state what you have tried. And a pro-tip "info coreutils" shows you kinda-man-pages for some really helpful commands.

Comment: why does `5678 400 murali` in your output. Shouldn't it be `1456 400 murali`?

Comment: Sorry it should be 1456 400 murali.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822465/sort-and-keep-a-unique-duplicate-which-has-the-highest-value-unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk's associative array:

```
awk '$2>m[$3]{m[$3]=$2; r[$3]=$0} END{for (i in r) print r[i]}' file
1456    400  murali
1234    200   suresh
8543    200   sanjith
```